# Jquery - Create URL from an associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have an associative array **urlvalue** with values as follows:

```
{"folder":"subscriber", "file":"setstatus", "alert":"yes", "id":"12"}
```

I would like to turn this array into a URL so that I can send the variables to another page. How can it be done using jquery so that they appear like this:

```
?folder=subscriber&file=setstatus&alert=yes&id=12
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a homework. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 8):

You need [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
var params = {"folder":"subscriber", "file":"setstatus", "alert":"yes", "id":"12"};
var str = jQuery.param(params);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the

> $.param(VALUE)

funciton.

Example:

```
var obj = {"folder":"subscriber", "file":"setstatus", "alert":"yes", "id":"12"},
    toParam= $.param(obj);

alert(toParam);
```

output:

> folder=subscriber&file=setstatus&alert=yes&id=12

Fillder: http://jsfiddle.net/BGjWT/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` method to turn each key-value pair into a string, then join the array of strings into a single string. Use the `encodeURICompontent` function to encode the keys and values correctly:

```
var urlvalue = {"folder":"subscriber", "file":"setstatus", "alert":"yes", "id":"12"};

var param = '?' + $.map(urlvalue, function(v, k) {
    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v);
}).join('&');

alert(param);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/sCn5U/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `http_build_query()` function:

http://phpjs.org/functions/http_build_query/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test = {"folder":"subscriber", "file":"setstatus", "alert":"yes", "id":"12"};
var queryString = "?folder=" + test.folder + "&file=" + test.file + "&alert=" + test.alert + "&id=" + test.id + "";
alert(queryString);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/asnzZ/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a plugin, [there are some nice ones that do the job.](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution that does not involve jQuery at all (I assume people post jQuery solutions because of the tag):

```
var combine = function(params) {
    var lst = [];
    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            lst.push(encodeURIComponent(key)+"="+encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
        }
    }
    return "?"+lst.join("&");
}
```